# Trying to run only 5 threads of selenium webdriver at once, repeating until 200 threads have been run

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, executorservice

I'm trying to get 5 threads of selenium webdriver to run at a given time, wait for those threads to finish, then open 5 more, repeating until ~200 threads are run. My code can open 5 threads and wait for them to finish before moving on, but when I try to put that in a loop and set the target to 10 threads (should be 5 threads that run and finish, then 5 threads that run and finish afterwards), it opens up all 10 threads at the same time. I'm concerned that if I up the target to 200 threads, it will overload the computer.

Based on an answer to another question asked here (cannot find it for the life of me), I swapped from using Thread to ExecutorService, which worked for knowing when the 5 threads are finished. I am not very experienced, so other than for/do-while/while loops (which I've all tried) I don't know what other looping I could try.

```
            LISTSPERSESSION = 10;
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            int listIndex = 0;
            do {
                boolean finished = false;
                //Goes until 5 lists are searched OR the number of lists per session is hit
                for(int i=0; i < 5 || listIndex < LISTSPERSESSION; i++) {
                    listIndex++;
                    int index = i;
                    es.execute(() -> v.searchDatabase(index));
                }
                es.shutdown();

                try {
                    finished = es.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(finished == true) {
                    if(listIndex == LISTSPERSESSION) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            } while(false);
```

It opens all 10 threads at once, instead of 5 at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule `i < 5 || listIndex < LISTSPERSESSION` will evaluate to `true` as long as listIndex < 10.

Switch the OR to AND: `i < 5 && listIndex < LISTSPERSESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

For loop condition should be in braces and also add && instead of || operator

(i < 5 && listIndex < LISTSPERSESSION)